# A Basic Question About Sample Space

Tags: probability

If a coin tossed twice then the sample space contains four elements. But, what if two coins tossed at the same time, is it contain 3 elements instead of 4?

I think, it is, because we do not know which coin gives head or tail. Or should we assume that the coins are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on whether the coins are considered different. Whether you should consider them different depends on the context though.

For example, say one coin is blue and the other is red. Then your sample space consists of pairs $(B,R)$, where $B,R$ can represent a heads or tails value for the blue and red coins respectively. Then clearly there are four possibilities: $(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)$. The important bit here being that $(H,T) \ne (T,H)$ - which would make sense, if the coins are considered different.

If the coins are not considered different or distinct, then what can appear? Two heads, one of each, or two tails. You might write this sample space as $\{HH,TT,TH\}$ then. (Note that we're not using ordered pairs: indeed, the "ordered" in that term is **very** important in our earlier discussion.)

Of course, bear in mind that this distinction also bears consequences on the probability. In the first case, each event in the sample space is equally likely, and in the second they are not! Introductory probability students can often make this mistake.

Comment: Yeah. I get it. But, what if it is not clear from the question that the coins are distinct or identical? Thanks.

Comment: For example, it is just "Two coins are tossed simultaneously..."

Comment: Considering there is no reason to consider them distinct as posed in the question, then I would likewise assume they're indistinct.

Comment: Ok. Did you have a book recommendation about probability?

Comment: I want to learn about how distinction affect the probability.